# Set new object property on *ngFor Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an object some like this:

```
this.obj = {{name: 'Hello 1'}, {'name': 'Hello 2'}}
```

I'm making a loop through this object on angular 2 (ionic2):

```
<div class"item" *ngFor="let item as obj"> 
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <span>{{item.count}}</span>
</div>
```

`item.count` doesn't exists, and, obviously, It will not be rendered in the view. But I need to instanciate this property in the view. In angular 1 I think something like `ng-init="item.count = 0"` should solve this issue, but It's not enabled in Angular 2.

Comment: *I need to instanciate this property in the view*: why would you need that? ng-init, in Angular 1, is explicitly documented as "almost never use this". Initialize your objects in the component. That's where it belongs.

Comment: The object is parsed from the API without the "count". I will implement buttons + and - to increase/decrease item.count.

Comment: So what? What prevents you from adding a count to every object after they're "parsed from the API"?

Comment: Of course, I was looking for a simpler solution, but I ended up solving this with a loop in the controller, before render.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE PER COMMENTS**

The solution appears to be a bug in Angular itself, as Aluan noted using dot property assignment results in "Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 41" so I have opened a [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17470)

**ORIGINAL**

If you want to do it in the template then you can dynamically add a property in JS (which TypeScript is a superset of, and therefore this is technically valid) via the `object['propertyName']` syntax.

The HTML for the template becomes

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of obj"> 
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <span>{{item['count'] ? item['count'] : item['count'] = 0}}</span>
  <button (click)="increment(item)">plus</button>
  <button (click)="decrement(item)">minus</button>
</div>
```

And the code for the button logic:

```
increment(item) {
  item.count++;
}

decrement(item) {
  item.count--;
}
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/b5fe87kFm2nxs3kabZRo?p=preview

Comment: Good solution. Thanks!

Comment: `item.count` works exactly the same as `item['count']` in TypeScript just like it does like it does in JavaScript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad you are correct and I am wrong, this is actually an Angular compiler quirk.

Change the Plunker's `item['count']` to `item.count` and the compiler will choke on the assignment with `item.count = 0` but correctly process the `item['count'] = 0`. Furthermore, setting just {{item.count}} breaks as it does not exist at run time per the original post.

Comment: Thank you, that is really interesting. I get the error only for the assignment and it is a deliberate behavor: _"Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 41"_. Given that, the fact `item['count'] = 0` succeeds is actually a bug. You may want to mention that.

Comment: Would you consider updating this answer? I'd like to turn my downvote into an upvote especially in light of the informative discussion we had in the above comments

Comment: @AluanHaddad github issue opened here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17470